# Im pulling a file that has different ascci values than I need. Python

Tags: python

Basically I have a `.txt` file that I need to decode. In example the is endcoded as rfc in the file. 
This is what I have at the moment.

```
line = open('encoded_2.txt','r')
for f in line:
    line = chr(ord(line[f])+2)
print(line)

infile.close()
```

I get this error:

> "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: please upload your file to produce a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of the conversion you're attempting.  I tried to preserve that conversion.  This code reads from the entire text file into `line` all at once.  Then it goes through each `ch` in the line, making the conversion and appending to `new_line`.  Hopefully that helps you on your way.

```
infile = open('encoded_2.txt','r')
line = infile.read()
new_line = ''
for f, ch in enumerate(line):
    new_line += chr(ord(ch) + 2)
print(new_line)
infile.close()
```